# When are nohup'd processes stopped during shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, runlevel, nohup

When I shutdown Ubuntu after I started a process using `nohup`, when and how is it getting stopped?

One of the scripts in `/etc/rc0.d/` should handle it, shouldn't? Is it `S20sendsigs`?

Comment: The answer is related to the version of Ubuntu you use... we have 2 methods: systemd on newer versions and upstart on older version. systemd uses a "ExecStop=" in the services on what to do whan a service is told t stop.  BUT ... "nohup" processes are generally not services so I reallllly doubt there is anything that scans the process table to find a process to stop it gracefully. Such processes are just killed when the power turns of. Something like a "kill init" or "kill {process 1}".

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to access my nohup'd program in `K99monitorix` (right before `S20sendsig`): Works.

Then I tried to access it in `S30urandom` (right afterwards): Does not work.

So it seems that it is indeed `S20sendsig` which kills nohup'd processes.