# Ubuntu cutting it's own power supply: What to do before power outage?

Tags: power-management, shutdown

I have an Ubuntu file server which I would like to switch on/off using a remote control electrical outlet. I also have a device which receives and sends remote control signals; it is connected via USB; I use a helper program to send signals. So instead of directly sending the poweroff signal to the outlet, I send a shutdown signal to Ubuntu. The idea is that Ubuntu iniates the shutdown and cuts its own power supply. This enables me later to start the computer by switchting on the power outlet via remote control.

As I understand, idealy, cutting power should be done in `/etc/rc0.d/S90halt`, correct? But at this point my helper program which could send the poweroff signal to the outlet was already killed.

What options do I have? Is it possible to keep my remote control program running? Could I start it in `S90halt` even though the disk is already unmounted?

Comment: You will need a daemon program to accomplish that. There is a similar program apcupsd for controlling ups via usb cable. I would look into that.

Comment: Yeah that ^^  See as an example https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2003/05/msg01998.html  (it is checking for `/etc/init.d/ups-monitor poweroff`)

Comment: Its UPS, or only outlet? if you send signal to outlet it cut off power before shutdown procedure was done. How do you send this signal, in this place you have unmounted network/disk.

Comment: It is just an outlet. So that is exactly the problem: When/how can I cut off power before shutdown has completed but without breaking anything.

Comment: Why you want to cut off this outlet? what kind/model of outlet it is? I have security poweroff based on arduino and relays. (i send signal to arduino by network or button and when system is off it cutoff power) it initialize halt by short circuit on powerbutton and monitor system by connection to powerledpins. its not so expensive, and easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way how to do it:

At boot I start my remote control helper program as nohup'd process. However, during shutdown it gets [killed by `S20sendsigs`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937911/when-are-nohupd-processes-stopped-during-shutdown/937925#937925). So I start it again using a new script `S21remotecontrol` which again uses nohup. The helper program starts an embedded web server. This way I just needed to add `curl http://localhost:8081/poweroff` to `S90halt`.

I am not sure why `curl` is actually available at `S90halt` because all file systems should have been unmounted at this point. Nevertheless, it does work. My work around is not used: I added a delay option so that `curl` could be called before unmounting but delaying the switch command a few seconds.

Important! The helper program *must not* write a log file since it will fail after unmounting during shutdown and may crash the program. For starting the helper I use: `nohup command >/dev/null 2>&1 &`.